# Adjacent sibling combinator with tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm iterating over list items in a for loop, so I only have **one** `li` I can apply styles to, so the peer class won't work in this case.

In CSS I can do this

```css
li + li {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

How can I achieve this same effect in tailwind?

Comment: Checkout https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#sibling-selector-variants

Comment: Peer doesn't help with what I need.

Comment: Have you tried using `@apply` directive?

Comment: Sure I can just use normal css with @apply. I'm looking for a tailwind-built solution so I don't need to write css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

Use the [space selector](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space) - `space-y-*` on the parent. It acts like `> * + *` in normal css.

Example:

```html
<ul class='space-y-5'>
   <li>my list item</li>
   <li>my list item</li>
   <li>my list item</li>
</ul>
```

This will apply a margin top to every `li` except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the child selector. Giving the parent div the class `[&>li:nth-child(n+2)]:mt-10` will fix the problem. You can check it out in the demo below.

[Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/paFFbZCJJW)

Answer (score 0):

You can style the first child with `first` modifier of the tailwind css. Following below is the example

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="list-disc text-green-700 p-8 space-y-4">
  <li class="first:text-blue-700">ListItem 1</li>
  <li class="first:text-blue-700">ListItem 2</li>
  <li class="first:text-blue-700">ListItem 3</li>
  <li class="first:text-blue-700">ListItem 4</li>
  <li class="first:text-blue-700">ListItem 5</li>
  <li class="first:text-blue-700">ListItem 6</li>
  <li class="first:text-blue-700">ListItem 7</li>
  <li class="first:text-blue-700">ListItem 8</li>
</div>
```

You can also view the demo [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/eF5jJAiGVN)